# I have trouble understanding the code for socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a beginner in the field of sockets and lately trying ti create a terminal chat app with that.I still have trouble understanding setblocking and select functions

"This is the code i have taken from a website i'm reading from and in the code if there is nothing in data, how does it mean that the socket has been disconnected and please also do explain what affect the setblocking in the server or the client does.I have read somewhere that setblocking allows to move on if the data has been fully not recieved,i'm not quite satisfied with the explaination.Please explain in simple words "

```
import select
import socket
import sys
import Queue

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
server.bind(server_address)
server.listen(5)
inputs = [ server ]

outputs = [ ]
message_queues = {}

while inputs:

 readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)

for s in readable:

 if s is server:

connection, client_address = s.accept()

connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)

 message_queues[connection] = Queue.Queue()

 else:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                message_queues[s].put(data)
                if s not in outputs:
                    outputs.append(s)
            else:
                if s in outputs:
                    outputs.remove(s)
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
```

Comment: where is `Queue` coming from? any links to the source you copied the code from? also why a downvote?

Comment: @Evgeny https://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/select/index.html

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html, at least that is standard documentation.

Comment: module of the week is for Python Version: 1.4 and later, very dated.

Comment: Please edit the question to fix the formatting.  There is some obviously wrong indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is nothing in data, how does it mean that the socket has been disconnected

The POSIX specification of [recv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) says:

> Upon successful completion, *recv*() shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be
> received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, *recv*() shall return 0. …

In the Python interface, return value 0 corresponds to a returned buffer of length 0, i. e. *nothing in `data`*.

> what affect the setblocking in the server or the client does.

The `setblocking(0)` sets the socket to non-blocking, i. e. if e. g. the `accept()` or `recv()` cannot be completed immediately, the operation fails rather than blocks until complete. In the given code, this can hardly happen, since the operations are not tried before they are possible (due to the use of `select()`). However, the example is bad in that it includes `output` in the `select()` arguments, resulting in a busy loop since `output` is writable most of the time.